# Como accesar al localhost de un servidor xampp de un pc por medio del movil

Tags: android, xampp, navegador-web

Buen día.
Espero su ayuda a una situación con mi movil y la pc en donde hago pruebas, trato de lograr que se visualice el servidor xampp de mi pc en el movil por medio del chrome, pero este me muestra el error de "192.168.x.x tardó demasiado en responder". En donde ingreso la ip local de mi pc, instale una app en mi movil que se llama "ES File Explorer" para comprobar la comunicación entre los dos dispositivos y no tuve problema alguno, solamente con el navegador Chrome.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar unas cosas ya que si el programa en ambiente web que tienes generado esta en el locahost no deberias tener problemas si apuntas a la Ip de la pc donde desarrollas:

- Revisa que las Ip's de ambos dispositivos (pc y android) sean estáticas.
- Has un ping desde tu pc al dispositivo para saber si tienes respuesta.
- Verifica el puerto de tu aplicación. Puede ser que tu aplicación se encuentra en un puerto específico como el :80 o el :8080 quedando de esta forma: localhost:80/my_aplicacion/
- Intenta llegar a la aplicación desde otro dispositivo local.

Así podrías ir descartando problemas.

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.